I'm using a custom transformation, the PNG is OK but the PDF is empty
This question is a follow up to Making a poster: how to place Artists in a Figure using mm and top-left origin
This code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

mm, dpi = 1/25.4, dpi
w, h = 841, 1189
trans = Affine2D().scale(mm*dpi).scale(1,-1).translate(0,h*mm*dpi)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(w*mm, h*mm), layout='none', dpi=dpi)
fig.patches.append(
    plt.Rectangle((230, 190), 40, 18, transform=trans))
fig.savefig('A0.pdf')
fig.savefig('A0.png')

produces an empty PDF, while the PNG file is correct.
Unfortunately the print shop with the wide inkjet plotter wants a PDF. While I could transform the raster file to PDF, I'd prefer to produce directly a correct PDF.
Is there something wrong in my code or it shouldn't happen and it's a bug I have to report to Matplotlib devs?

This code, that does not use the custom transformation, produces a correct PDF, with the rectangle in the correct position and the right dimensions.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mm, dpi = 1/25.4, 96
w, h = 841, 1189
fig = plt.figure(dpi=dpi, layout='none', figsize=(w*mm,h*mm))
fig.patches.append(plt.Rectangle((660/w, 1-1000/h), 40/w, -40/h,
                                 transform=fig.transFigure))
fig.savefig('A0.pdf')


UPDATE
...
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(w*mm, h*mm), layout='none', dpi=dpi)
fig.patches.append(
    plt.Rectangle((230, 190), 40, 18, transform=trans))
fig.patches.append(
    plt.Rectangle((600/w, 1-190/h), 40/w, -18/h, transform=fig.transFigure))
fig.savefig('A0.pdf')

produces a non empty PDF, but only the second rectangle, drawn w/o using the custom transformation, is visible.

If you ever find yourself plotting something and having to specify the dpi manually, you are going to have problems if you try and save at a different dpi.  The correct way to do this so it is dpi invariant, but still in physical space, is:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

mm = 1.0/25.4
w, h = 841.0, 1182.0
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(w*mm, h*mm), layout='none')

trans = Affine2D().scale(mm).scale(1,-1).translate(0,h*mm) + fig.dpi_scale_trans
fig.patches.append(
    plt.Rectangle((230, 190), 40, 18, transform=trans))


In this throwback thread from July 2010, they suggest to hardcode dpi=72 into the PDF renderer for backward compatibility with older PDF specs. And indeed, when I set it in savefig, the rectangle (and any other artists added to the figure with a custom transformation) renders fine :
fig.savefig("A0.pdf", dpi=72)

In my experiments, I've found that fig.savefig("A0.pdf", dpi=72) is not enough, you also have to fig = plt.figure(…, dpi=72) otherwise no output in PDF.

To solve this, you can use the transform parameter more effectively by applying
transformations that are more compatible with the PDF backend. Specifically, you
can try to avoid complex custom transformations and rely more on the
transformations provided by Matplotlib, such as fig.transFigure, which works

consistently across different backends.
